# Django serializer won't save to database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

im making small rest api that takes ip address then sends it to ipstack and saves returned data do database. The problem is my data is not saving when calling serializer.save. I'm sure that this is some small issue but i spend soo much time looking at this code that i don't see anything

Don't mind if the data from ip isn't correct here I've changed it
let's start with the **models.py**

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=8)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=0)
    continent_code = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    continent_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    region_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ip)
```

**serializer**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        exclude = ['id']
```

**vievws**

```py
ip = '89.64.124.126'
if ip:
   try:
      data = location_search.get_location(ip)
      if data is None:
         return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,)
      except:
         return Response("Our services are temporarily unavailable", status=503,)

      serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data)
      print(serializer)
      print(serializer.is_valid())
      if serializer.is_valid():
         serializer.save()
         return Response("Data was successfully added", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,)
      else:
          return Response("Database error occurred, try again later",status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,)
```

this is what i get when printing

```py
LocationSerializer(data={'ip': '89.64.124.126', 'type': 'ipv4', 'continent_code': 'EU', 'continent_name': 'Europe', 'country_code': 'PL', 'country_name': 'Poland', 'region_code': 'MZ', 'region_name': 'Mazovia', 'city': 'Warsaw', 'zip': '00-877', 'latitude': 42.239688873291016, 'longitude': 10.98748016357422, 'location': {'geoname_id': 756135, 'capital': 'Warsaw', 'languages': [{'code': 'pl', 'name': 'Polish', 'native': 'Polski'}], 'country_flag': 'http://assets.ipstack.com/flags/pl.svg', 'country_flag_emoji': '', 'country_flag_emoji_unicode': 'U+1F1F5 U+1F1F1', 'c  alling_code': '48', 'is_eu': True}}):
    ip = CharField(max_length=15)
    type = CharField(max_length=6)
    latitude = DecimalField(decimal_places=8, max_digits=10)
    longitude = DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits=10)
    continent_code = CharField(max_length=2)
    continent_name = CharField(max_length=20)
    country_code = CharField(max_length=10)
    country_name = CharField(max_length=70)
    region_code = CharField(max_length=10)
    region_name = CharField(max_length=50)
    city = CharField(max_length=100)
    zip = CharField(max_length=10)

False
```

Comment: fields = "__all__"

put this above line into your Serializer Meta class.

Comment: When i put this before mmy meta class i get 'str' object has no attribute 'values and when im putting this instead of exclude nothing happens

Comment: Use this **fields='__all__'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set models.FloatField() on lat and longitude instead of decimal field

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to check the errors, and fix them.

```
print(serializer.errors)
```

Comment: but i need to call errors after is_valid() but serializer is not valid so i don't get anny info

Comment: Refer https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation. You can call errors even if serializer is not valid.

Comment: im not getting anything

Comment: share your updated code with print and traceback.